# CakePHP Foreach Find Loop Issue

Tags: cakephp, loops

Now, I have spaced the only right output I get, that number is a step_id but then it does not give me all the over IDs. Like I said, I was hoping the debug would print/echo ALL step_ids on the screen when the user_id in my steps table, is the right type of id.

DEBUG OUTPUT BELOW:

app/controllers/steps_controller.php (line 109)
1323
Notice (8): Undefined offset: 1 [APP/controllers/steps_controller.php, line 109]app/controllers/steps_controller.php (line 109)

Notice (8): Undefined offset: 2 [APP/controllers/steps_controller.php, line 109]app/controllers/steps_controller.php (line 109)

Notice (8): Undefined offset: 3 [APP/controllers/steps_controller.php, line 109]app/controllers/steps_controller.php (line 109)

Notice (8): Undefined offset: 4 [APP/controllers/steps_controller.php, line 109]app/controllers/steps_controller.php (line 109)

Notice (8): Undefined offset: 5 [APP/controllers/steps_controller.php, line 109]app/controllers/steps_controller.php (line 109)

Notice (8): Undefined offset: 6 [APP/controllers/steps_controller.php, line 109]app/controllers/steps_controller.php (line 109)

Notice (8): Undefined offset: 7 [APP/controllers/steps_controller.php, line 109]app/controllers/steps_controller.php (line 109)

Notice (8): Undefined offset: 8 [APP/controllers/steps_controller.php, line 109]app/controllers/steps_controller.php (line 109)

UPDATE :

I am not sure if this was an error or not but in my foreach loop I had 'Step.user_id', when then find command is pointing to the Step table anyway, so I changed it! But It still does not work.

With, the new code below, more or less the same code it was. I have used a debug command to print ALL the step Ids when the user id in the steps table matches to the user id that are only of the right role, e.g. >3. However the debug only gives me one returned result! And then 'Undefined offset:' 1 to 8.

Any ideas of what I am doing wrong? Please??

```
        foreach($getUserIds as $k=>$data) {
            //$StepConditions = ;

            $getStepIds = $this->Step->find('all', array('conditions' => array('user_id' => $getUserIds[$k]['User']['id'])));

            debug($getStepIds[$k]['Step']['id']);

        }
```

---

I have searched on here but I can't seem to find anyone who as posted about this problem, so I hope you can help!

Ok, the main aim of my function is to get all the 'steps' out of my database but only when the user_id is > 3.

I am very new the CakePHP, so I am not very good with these find commands let. Now, as it stands, If I debug $getSteps, it only gives me 0,1 & 2 numbered arrays. All the info in theme is right but I do know there is more than three steps done by the user group.

Then I debug, $getUserIds, it gives me all the user Ids I wanted but not all the steps done my all this users, just three I said.

Any hope is most welcome!

Many Thanks Glenn

```
function Breakdown($id = null) {
    $getUserIds = $this->Step->User->find(
        'all',
        array(
            'conditions' => array('role_id' => 2)
             )
        );

    foreach ($getUserIds as $k=>$data) {

        $getSteps = $this->Step->find(
                'all', 
                array(
                      'conditions' => array('Step.user_id' => $getUserIds[$k]['User']['id'])
                     ) 
        );
        debug($getSteps);

    }

die();
} //End of Breakdown() function
```

Comment: can you post the output of the debug, and also what you expect the output to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its OK,

I have solved my problems! I think the users were assigned to each step but they are only assigned to the project, therefore it does not work.

What I am going to do is make a new table and build my links to each step for each user.

Many Many Thanks For All The Help and support you guys have given me on this!

Glenn Curtis.

Answer (score 0):

You can include a ">" in your condition to get all steps where user_id is greater than 3:

```
$getSteps = $this->Step->find('all', array('conditions' => array('Step.user_id >' => 3));
```

Comment: Umm that will not work, the user_id is never set to 3, the role_id is what controls the user level! User_id is in the step table but role_id is only in the users table! Umm I look at maybe doing something like you said, but by using the users table! But many thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 0):

As you said in your question: "the main aim of my function is to get all the 'steps' out of my database but only when the user_id is > 3"

Here is the code sample:

```
function Breakdown($id = null) {
    $this->User->bindModel(array(
                                 'hasMany' => array( 
                                                    'Step' => array( 
                                                                    'className' => 'Step',
                                                                    'foreignKey' => 'user_id'
                                                                   )
                                                   )
                                 )
                           ); //dynamically bind model
    $userWithSteps = $this->User->find('all', array('conditions' => array('User.role_id' => 2)));

    }
pr(userWithSteps );
die();
} //End of artistsBreakdown() function
```

And it is done. You don't need to use foreach loop. Kindly ask if it not worked for you.

Comment: Well, I try it for something else I am working on now, but read my answer! My database is not built to hold the data in that way. But I will try your code to see what it can do. Never seen bindModel before, I take it that it is a built in CakePHP command? Very cool code anyway, so many thanks for trying to help.